# Combining three slider values into one Texblock Text / Label Content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently working on a User Interface in which the user can select three values via three separate sliders. I've got three textblocks in front of the sliders to indicate the current value of the specific slider:

In the .xaml:

```
<Label Content="Sample Selection" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label Content="Patient Samples (max 64)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
<Slider x:Name="SampleAmountSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="64" ValueChanged="SampleAmountSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="SampleSliderValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,16,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label Content="Calibrators (max 7)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
<Slider x:Name="CalAmountSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="7" ValueChanged="CalAmountSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="CalSliderValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label Content="Control Samples (max 4)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
<Slider x:Name="ControlAmountSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="4" ValueChanged="ControlAmountSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="ControlSliderValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label Content="Total Sample Preparations Selected:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TotalPrepValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,110,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

In .xaml.cs:

```
private void SampleAmountSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        SampleSliderValue.Text = Math.Round(e.NewValue, 0).ToString();
    }

private void CalAmountSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        CalSliderValue.Text = Math.Round(e.NewValue, 0).ToString();
    }

private void ControlAmountSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        ControlSliderValue.Text = Math.Round(e.NewValue, 0).ToString();
    }
```

What I want is the last text block (named TotalPrepValue) to contain a sum of the amount of patient samples, amount of calibrators and amount of control samples.

I'm not sure if I'm asking a lot or things are unclear (if so, please let me know. I'll answer as fast as possible).
The thing is that I'm a very inexperienced programmer, yet willing to learn!
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to use containers (`Grid` with row/columns, `StackPanel`, etc.) instead of `Margin` for creating layouts. As for the problem, move calculation into method which all event handlers call, set the text for sum there. Much easier approach is to start using bindings + MVVM, then creating property `public double Sum => ...` and rising it notification (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) in every property used to calculate sum is the right way.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for your response! I'll look into this as soon as possible and I'll let you know if I succeeded!

Comment: binding + mvvm Much easier approach? you serious? thats waaayy harder for a guy who is starting. That might be the "pro" way to do what he wants, but its certainly not the easiest, he can just create a method that updates the text whenever any slider changes, really simple.

Comment: Try IMultiValueConverter

Comment: @Ricardo: MVVM is not difficult, and since WPF is designed to work that way, implementing other solutions will be at least as hard in the short run, and harder in the long run, because MVVM will scale to whatever other implementation goals the OP has in WPF.

Comment: @Sinatr Since many people here talk about using MVVM I'm going to look into it and start learning. My question has been solved by the way! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, as others have suggested, use `IMultiValueConverter` in this scenario. But it's my opinion that, while a useful tool in other scenarios, that's the wrong tool for the job here. The reason being that in this case, it would be used to perpetuate the inappropriate use of UI elements as a place to store your non-UI data.

You will be much better served, while writing WPF programs, if you commit yourself to following the MVVM-style of programming WPF was intended to be used with. The term "MVVM" means literally "model, view, view-model". From that point of view, there will always be special-purpose "adapter" types between the model and the view. But it's been my experience that the important part of the MVVM paradigm is to be strict about keeping view logic separate from model logic, and this can often be done without the extra layer of the "view model" types. This puts MVVM in the same set of tools as MVC ("model, view, controller") and MVP ("model, view, presenter").

The key to all of these is that you have some business logic which is represented in model data structures, implemented by types that provide some form of value-changed notification (in WPF, the primary mechanism here is `INotifyPropertyChanged`), and then also view logic which is represented completely separately (in WPF, the view is mostly, and in many cases entirely, declared in XAML).

In your example, this means we'd want a model data structure that represents the data you are interested in: the sample, calibrator, control, and total prep counts. The last one being simply the sum of the first three. As long as we have a class that can keep track of these, and correctly update the summed value when any of the other three change, we can bind this directly to a view declared in XAML, without the use of any C# code-behind at all.

For example:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _sampleCount;
    public int SampleCount
    {
        get { return _sampleCount; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _sampleCount, value, OnCountChanged); }
    }

    private int _calibratorCount;
    public int CalibratorCount
    {
        get { return _calibratorCount; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _calibratorCount, value, OnCountChanged); }
    }

    private int _controlCount;
    public int ControlCount
    {
        get { return _controlCount; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _controlCount, value, OnCountChanged); }
    }

    private int _totalPrepCount;
    public int TotalPrepCount
    {
        get { return _totalPrepCount; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _totalPrepCount, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnCountChanged(int previousValue)
    {
        TotalPrepCount = SampleCount + CalibratorCount + ControlCount;
    }

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The above class has four properties, one property for each of the values we want to keep track of.
- Three of the properties are just simple value containers. There is a callback method that is called whenever any of those are modified, and in that method the code simply sets the fourth property to the sum of the three.
- The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface has just a single member, the `PropertyChanged` event. You will find when dealing with MVVM-style code, it's helpful to have a base class that actually implements this event, and a helper method like the `_UpdateField()` method shown above, which property setters can call to handle the repetitive logic needed for each such property. In the example above, I've combined all of this logic into a single class for the sake of simplifying the example, but you'll probably want to keep a suitable base class around (I and many other people have configured snippets in Visual Studio to easily insert this boilerplate code into a project).

With a view model so-defined, the XAML is simplified to look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO45170241SliderExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO45170241SliderExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <Label Content="Sample Selection" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Patient Samples (max 64)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,14,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="64"
            Value="{Binding SampleCount}" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,16,0,0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SampleCount}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Calibrators (max 7)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,40,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="7"
            Value="{Binding CalibratorCount}" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,42,0,0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CalibratorCount}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Control Samples (max 4)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,66,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" Width="160" Maximum="4"
            Value="{Binding ControlCount}" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,68,0,0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ControlCount}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Total Sample Preparations Selected:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="10,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,110,0,0"
               FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding TotalPrepCount}"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

*(Aside: other than changing to support the MVVM approach, I did not modify your basic UI declarations at all. I do agree that another thing you'll want to start gaining familiarity with is how to take advantage of WPF's various layout containers and element styling features. But I think that introducing those here would just confuse matters. By keeping your original UI mostly intact, you can focus on just those things that are different from what you originally had, helping you understand better the data binding aspect without distraction.)*

In this implementation, there is *no* code whatsoever added to the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file. All that's in that file is the default call to `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor, provided by Visual Studio's template for WPF projects.

In the XAML, on the other hand, I've replaced the event handler subscriptions with bindings straight to the `Slider.Value` properties. Note also that the `TextBlock.Text` properties are also bound to the same properties. In this way, WPF does all the heavy lifting of storing slider values in a business-logic-only data structure, as well as of then redisplaying those values in text fields in the view. You'll note that WPF even handles conversion between the various data types: the view model stores `int` values, but the sliders use `double` and the text blocks of course use `string`.

And of course, the `TotalPrepCount` field is bound to the `TextBlock.Text` property of interest for display as well.

Finally, I'll note that even in your simple example, you have additional places where one might want to apply this data binding approach. In particular, your sliders each have maximum values, which are hard-coded into the view. The point of MVVM is for the view to not have to encapsulate *any* knowledge about the business logic. This would include not having to know the full range of values permissible (*).

So, your view model could also have e.g. a `MaxSampleCount` property, which is bound both to the `Slider.Maximum` property, and to the `Label.Content` property. In the latter case, you can use the `Binding.StringFormat` property to have the value incorporated into text as appropriate. For example:

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding MaxSampleCount, StringFormat=Patient Samples (max {0})" ... />
```

I will readily admit that when I first started trying to use WPF, after years and years of using UI APIs like the native Win32 controls, MFC, Windows Forms, Java's APIs (Swing, AWT, SWT), and even Mac OS's Cocoa framework (which uses a form of data binding, but not the declarative UI like XAML), I struggled to change my thinking away from the procedural approach used in all those other APIs to get used to the mixed declarative and procedural approach used with WPF.

But I was trying to learn it strictly from the documentation provided by MSDN, which is densely written at best, most often just plain difficult to follow, and in many cases, completely useless. If someone had just shown me an example like what I've shown above (and they did exist, even back then…I just didn't know where they were), I would have seen back then just how easy the basic MVVM approach is, and how much more quickly one can write a WPF program if one follows that approach.

I hope the above helps you get on track for productive use of WPF, and shows you the basics in an easy-to-understand way.

Comment: Thank you very much! It all seems to work! I'm going to test out the other solution that is described above as well just to see if I can learn some more. Thank you again and I will look into the whole MVVM approach as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, this is what I would do. However if you like it than please go also upvote @JerryNixon 's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074128/wpf-xaml-calculating-total-of-text-box-values) since it's basically just a re-factoring to use sliders instead of his example and he deserves more praise. Normally I'd have just pointed you to it directly but I know how it is when you're just getting started with something and a clearer PoC can be more useful.

Anyway, here ya go, a pretty picture to start...

[image]

The XAML;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SumConverter x:Key="MySumConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>


    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel.Resources>            
            <Style TargetType="Slider">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Slider x:Name="Slider1"></Slider>
        <Slider x:Name="Slider2"></Slider>
        <Slider x:Name="Slider3"></Slider>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1}"/>
            <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider2}"/>
            <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider3}"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="______________________"/>
            <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
            <Run>
                <Run.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MySumConverter}"
                                  StringFormat="{}{0:C}"
                                  FallbackValue="Error" TargetNullValue="Null">
                        <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="Slider1"/>
                        <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="Slider2"/>
                        <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="Slider3"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Run.Text>
            </Run>
        </TextBlock>            

    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

The Converter;

```
public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double _Sum = 0;
        if (values == null)
            return _Sum;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            double _Value;
            if (double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out _Value))
                _Sum += _Value;
        }
        return _Sum;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: A bit strange naming of local variables, underscore + Pascal? Camel is more standard (looking at msdn examples, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)).

Comment: Thank you very much! Two solutions to my problem have been given and both are very useful! Nice image btw ;)

Comment: @sinatr as mentioned, the converter is not mine. Was just a quickie thrown together answer but I agree.